# Error in unziping a file downloaded from S3 using python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto, unzip

I have a zip file in `S3` which I am trying to download and then unzip it.

I coded these lines:

```
conn = S3Connection('','')
bucket = conn.get_bucket('buck1')
key = bucket.get_key("folder1/foldr2/file1.gz")

f = open('/folder1/folder2/file1.gz', 'w')
key.get_file(f)
f.close()

cmd = 'unzip /folder1/folder2/file1.gz'
system(cmd)
```

But this gives **following error**:

```
End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
Archive:  /folder1/folder2/file1.gz
a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /folder1/folder2/file1.gz or
        /folder1/folder2/file1.gz.zip, and cannot find /folder1/folder2/file1.gz.ZIP, period.
```

I had tried this code also to unzip but this also gave error as `cannot be unzipped as this does not seems a zip file`:

```
zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile('/folder1/folder2/file1.gz', 'r')
zip_ref.extractall('/folder1/folder2/')
zip_ref.close()
```

I know the error comes when there is some problem with the zip file but what I don't understand is I am simply pulling the file from `S3` and trying to unzip it. How can I resolve this error and get the desired outcome?

**Note:** **I cannot unzip the file manually also on my machine (linux). I can see the downloaded file but cannot unzip it and get error.Also if i download the file manually from s3 and then manually unzip it then it unzips without any error.**

Comment: Have you verified that the file has dowoaded manually? If so, can you unzip it manually too?

Comment: @thefragileomen yes i can see the zip file on my machine and but I cannot unzip it manually. It gives error as `unable to expand the file`

Comment: Is this being run on a Linux OS?

Comment: @thefragileomen this is run on a linux (mac). Also please see my updated comment above. I cannot unzip it manually though I can see the file downloaded on my machine

Comment: I think that during the downloading process from `s3` the files is getting corrupted. Is my way of downloading the file correct?

Comment: If you can't manually unzip it, it could be a corrupted zip file. Do you know the hash / checksum of the remote file to compare it to your downloaded copy to ensure they are the same?

Comment: @thefragileomen no I don't know the hash/checksum of the remote file. is there a way I can do it?

Comment: Please note that Linux is not Mac OS X. They merely use the same command shell. Also note that you are decompressing gzip files, not unzipping them.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, you cannot use `unzip` to open a gzip archive. `unzip` is for .ZIP files only. Use the `gunzip` command for .gz files:

```
cmd = 'gunzip /folder1/folder2/file1.gz'
system(cmd)
```

**EDIT:**

If the file is still corrupted, you should make sure that it's actually a gzip file. Try the following:

```
hd /folder1/folder2/file1.gz | head
```

You should get something like:

```
00000000  1f 8b 08 08 0e 7f fc 50  00 03 63 6f 70 79 5f 63  |.......P..copy_c|
```

Make sure that the forst two octets after the `00000000` is `1f 8b`, which is the header for a gzip file.

Comment: I did but still got error as `unexpected end of file.uncompress failed`

Comment: is hd at the beginning a command? I get `hd: command not found` error

Comment: You can try replacing `hd` with `hexdump`

Comment: when I do this then I see 10 records. one of them has `1f 8b` but others do not have that

Comment: Ok so look like this is indeed a gzip file that is simply corrupted. You should try working with a different gzip file to verify nothing is wrong with your code. Creating a gzip file is easy: `gzip myfile` which will spit out `myfile.gz`

Comment: when i download a file manually and unzip it manually then it expands fine with no error

Comment: When you download the file manually, check the file size using `stat file`. Do the same for the file you downloaded via Python. They probably are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

While it is likely that the file is not a good .gz file (and as mentioned you can not use unzip to handle a .gz gzip file) there is another way to download the file without using a file handle explicitly.

based on your code:

```
key.set_contents_to_file('/path/to/file.gz')
```

you could also look into the gzip module
https://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html